# Trazer resultado em uma linha para join entre tabelas com relacionamento 1:N

Tags: sql-server, select, join

Estou com o seguinte problema no **SQL Server**
Tenho as tabelas `CLIENTE` e `TELEFONE`, com um relacionamento de **1:N** entre elas:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
       CPF CHAR(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
       , NOME VARCHAR(500)     
);

CREATE TABLE TELEFONE(
   ID_TELEFONE INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
   , CPF CHAR(11) NOT NULL
   , NUMERO VARCHAR(11)
   , CLASSIFICACAO INT DEFAULT(10)
   , FONTE VARCHAR(10)
   , DT_FONTE DATE
   , FOREIGN KEY (CPF) REFERENCES CLIENTE(CPF)
);
```

Quando faço o select com join das duas tabelas retorna assim:

```
CPF         |   NOME |   NUMERO

11111111111 |   jow1 |  992226801

11111111111 |   jow1 |  992226802

11111111111 |   jow1 |  992226803

11111111111 |   jow1 |  992226804

11111111111 |   jow1 |  992226805

11111111111 |   jow1 |  992226806

11111111111 |   jow1 |  992226807

11111111111 |   jow1 |  992226808

11111111111 |   jow1 |  992226809

11111111111 |   jow1 |  992226810

22222222222 |   jow2 |  26999861

22222222222 |   jow2 |  26999862

22222222222 |   jow2 |  26999863

22222222222 |   jow2 |  26999864
```

Mas eu preciso que retorne em uma unica linha, assim:

```
CPF         |   NOME |   NUMERO_1 | NUMERO_2  |  NUMERO_3 |  NUMERO_4 | ...

11111111111 |   jow1 |  992226801 | 992226802 | 992226803 | 992226804 | ...

22222222222 |   jow2 |  26999861  | 26999862  | 26999863  | 26999864  | ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar PIVOT para transformar linhas em colunas:https://www.devmedia.com.br/pivot-no-sql-server-invertendo-linhas-e-colunas-em-um-exemplo-real/28318